# Change the way my output is displayed in C program?

Tags: c

Sorry for bad topic name, i couldn't think of any. I have created this program that gets 7 values, add them and prints average, at the end it prints all the entered values in this format:

```
10, 15, 20, 15, 30, 45, 50,
```

I want it to display a comma after every value but after the last value I want to display dot like this:

```
10, 15, 20, 15, 30, 45, 50.
```

My code:

```
float sumFunk(float a, float b) {
         return ( (float) a + b);
}
float avgFunk(float a, float b) {
         return (a / b);
}

int main(void) {

float avg = 0;
float cWeek[7] = {0};
int counter, sum = 0;

for ( counter = 0; counter <= 6; counter++) {
    printf("Enter Temperature of day %d: ", counter+1); scanf("%f", &cWeek[counter]);
    sum = sumFunk(sum, cWeek[counter]);
}
avg = avgFunk(sum, counter);
printf("Average Temp of %d days: %.2f \n", counter, avg);

for ( counter = 0; counter <= 5; counter++ ) {
    printf("%.2f, ", cWeek[counter]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after the following printf line:

```
printf("Average Temp of %d days: %.2f \n", counter, avg);
```

add this line:

```
int last_element = cWeek [ sizeof cWeek ];
```

and then at the end add this if loop:

```
if ( last_element == '\0' ) { //whenever a list ends, this '\0' end character is added as well.

printf("%.2f. ", cWeek[counter]);

}
```

Comment: This answer is a long way from correct (despite having the tick). `cWeek` is a `float`, so the index `sizeof cWeek` does not have much to do with the length of the array. The last element would be `cWeek[ sizeof cWeek / sizeof cWeek[0] - 1]`. Next, whether this element is 0 or not makes no difference, as the list might not end in 0. And comparing the current element to the last element is also unreliable, as the list may have duplicate elements.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to accomplish this task is with code like this

```
for ( counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++ )
    printf("%.2f%s", cWeek[counter], (counter + 1 == 7) ? ".\n" : ", " );
```

`counter + 1 == 7` checks to see if the loop is about to end.  If so, the string `.\n` is appended to the output, otherwise a comma and space are appended.

Comment: Not so complicated. Just `printf("\r\r.\n");` at the end of output.

Comment: I think you meant to say `printf("\b\b.\n");` but that's not a good idea if the program output is redirected to a file.  Better just to do it right, and anyways it's fewer lines of code the way I suggested :)